# Passing array to one of named parameters in script block?

Tags: powershell, named-parameters, invoke-command, splat, scriptblock

I am trying to figure out a way to pass an array to a named parameter in a separate script. However, I could not find any solution.

Test2.ps1:

```
param(
    [int]$a,
    [int]$b,
    [int]$c,
    [string[]]$d
)

write-host "`$a = $a"
write-host "`$b = $b"
write-host "`$c = $c"
write-host "`$d:" -nonewline
foreach($str in $d) {
    write-host " $str" -nonewline
}
write-host
```

Main script:

```
$arr = @("abc", "def", "ghi")
$params = @{
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;
    d = $arr
}

#invoke-command -filepath "test2.ps1" -ArgumentList 1,2,3,@("abc", "def", "ghi")
$scriptPath = "test2.ps1"
$sb = [scriptblock]::create(".{$(get-content $ScriptPath -Raw)} $(&{$args} @params)")
invoke-command -scriptblock $sb
```

When executed, I got output that

```
$d:System.Object[]
```

The line below was copied from another Stackoverflow answer but I don't quite understand how it worked for the first 3 named parameters.

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::create(".{$(get-content $ScriptPath -Raw)} $(&{$args} @params)")
```

Especially the "$(&{$args} @params)" part. I have basic understanding of splatting, but this is beyond me. Much appreciated if someone can explain the syntax a bit for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `@params` inside an expandable string, you're forcing the parser to convert the resulting output to a string, and the default behavior of `ToString()` (if not overridden) is to just return the type name of the object in question.

Simply wait until you call the script before you supply the parameters:

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("$(get-content $ScriptPath -Raw)")
& $sb $args @params
```

or, if you want to *dot-source* the script with specific parameters:

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("$(get-content $ScriptPath -Raw)")
& {.$sb $args @params}
```